# Tras createsuperuser con managers: AttributeError: 'UserManager' object has no attribute '_create_user'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

Tras crear superuser por comando (`username`, `email`, `password` y confirmación de password) utilizando managers, me devuelve el siguiente error:

```
AttributeError: 'UserManager' object has no attribute '_create_user'
```

¿Qué sucede? Gracias.

---

Archivo `users/models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from .managers import UserManager

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M','Masculino'),
        ('F','Femenino'),
        ('O','Otros'),
    )

    username = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, blank=True)
    
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email',]

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username
    
    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name + '' + self.last_name
```

Archivo `users/managers.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

class UserManager(BaseUserManager, models.Manager):
    
    def create_user(self, username, email, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = email,
            is_staff = is_staff,
            is_superuser = is_superuser,
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self.db)
        return user
    

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(username, email, password, True, True, **extra_fields)
```

Comment: Django 1.8 ? modelo que hereda AbstractUser model.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El manager [`BaseUserManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager), no tiene un método `_create_user` (de donde lo sacas?). Dicho manager solo tiene los siguientes métodos:

- `normalize_email`
- `get_by_natural_key`
- `make_random_password`

---

Por otra parte no es necesario la siguiente herencia:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager, models.Manager):
```

El manager [`BaseUserManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager) ya hereda de `models.Manager`, no se si lo estas tratando como un mixin...

Entonces tu manager debería ser así:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password, is_staff=False, **extra_fields):

        # Validaciones....

        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(email), # !
            is_staff = is_staff,
            **extra_fields
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        return self.create_user(
            username = username,
            email=email,
            password = password,
            is_superuser = True,
            **extra_fields
        )
```

Le quite el parámetro `is_superuser` del método `create_user`, pues no tiene sentido crear un método `create_superuser` si puedes crear un super usuario desde el método `create_user`, no tiene sentido.

Por otra parte no te recomiendo poner ese `**extra_fields`, porque de igual manera puedes crear un super usuario desde el método `create_user` lo cual no tiene sentido (esto lo puedes ver en el mismo método `create_superuser`).

El manager ideal seria el siguiente:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, username, email, password, is_staff=False):
        user = self.model(
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(email), 
            is_staff = is_staff
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            username = username,
            email=email,
            password = password,
            is_staff = True
        )

        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: ¡Claro que me ayuda Julio Cesar! Gracias por detallarlo tanto por cierto. Si me permites una pregunta, por qué create_user commit en True y create_superuser commit en False? Por otro lado, con tu manager ideal, me devuelve: TypeError: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'. Gracias.

Comment: Lo siento, me confundí respecto a los `ModelForms`, eso del "commit" solo hay en los `ModelForms` jajaja, ya actualice mi respuesta (ignora lo del `commit` xD).

Comment: Nada que sentir, y muy agradecido por tu interés Julio Cesar, como muchas otras veces. Te imagino trabajando en una gran empresa de desarrollo... tú sólo, sin necesidad de equipo ni nada. Siempre tienes todas las respuestas. xD (bromeo). Gracias.

Comment: Jaja ni trabajo, tengo apenas 16 jaja, un gusto broda xd

Comment: ¿Tan jóven? Jaja! Venga, hago como que me lo creo. ; ) Gracias por todo Julio Cesar.